# Add one to a major diagonal of a matrix given a coordinate point

Tags: matrix, algorithm

```
n = 10;

board = ConstantArray[0, {n, n}];

diag1[x0_, y0_] :=
 Module[{x = x0, y = y0},
  While[{x != 1 || y != 1},
   x--;
   y--
   ];
  While[{x != n + 1 || y != n + 1},
   board[[x, y]]++;
   x++;
   y++
   ]
  ]
```

I have an n by n matrix of all zeroes. On a given coordinate in the matrix, I need to increase everything in its major diagonal by one. A runchart of this works fine. All that this does, is increase the (x-1,y-1) by one. I believe that the while loops are only executing the statements once, but I can't be sure.

Comment: Just edited the title of your question. Please re-edit if I missed your point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your definition uses `While` incorrectly, in that the first argument should evaluate to `True` when you want to keep looping. The braces you wrap around the first argument mean that instead of `True` or `False` you'll get `{True}` or `{False}`. `While` has to see plain `True`; anything else is treated like `False`.

Also, your conditions should be conjunctions, not disjunctions. Here is a working edit:

```
diag1[x0_, y0_] :=
 Module[{x = x0, y = y0},
  While[x != 1 && y != 1,
   x--;
   y--
   ];
  While[x != n + 1 && y != n + 1,
   board[[x, y]]++;
   x++;
   y++
   ]
  ]
```

Here's another way that I think is a bit more idiomatic for *Mathematica* (and which includes some input-checking as well as the state-mutating aspect of your example definition):

```
ClearAll@diag1;
SetAttributes[diag1, HoldFirst];
diag1[m_Symbol /; MatrixQ@m, r_, c_] /;
  (1 <= r <= #1 && 1 <= c <= #2 & @@ Dimensions@m) :=
 m += SparseArray[Band[{r, c} - Min[r, c] + 1] -> 1, Dimensions@m]

board = ConstantArray[0, {10, 6}];
diag1[board, 8, 2];
diag1[board, 6, 5];
diag1[board, 1, 5];
board // MatrixForm
```

Comment: Can you please explain why the choice of ands instead of ors? I do not need both conditions to be true, I just want whichever becomes true first. Wouldn't that be an or? Also I tried modifying my statement to your first one and it does not work as intended. Instead I am getting the same issue.

Comment: @ibayibay1 You want `&&` because you want to 'back up' `x` and `y` as long as neither `x` nor `y` equal `1`. As soon as one of them equals `1`, you're at a top-left edge and you want to stop the loop. Likewise for the second loop, but for the bottom-right edge. I think your intuition toward `||` was originally pointing you to the equivalent `!(x == 1 || y == 1)` (via De Morgan) for the first loop. Re it not working as intended, I've tested it again and it works correctly. If you're still stuck, show me your input (including `diag1` definition) and your output.

Comment: I got it working. I was using `while` instead of `While`. Simple mistake. Thank you though.

Comment: @ibayibay1 That's alright, I've been bitten by casing bugs when using other languages, too. But, I should definitely offer an apology to you here: I edited `while` in your original question to `While` and failed to mention this change to you, as I incorrectly assumed it was just a typo during the question write-up and not a typo from your actual definition (and thus an integral part of the question). Sorry for the oversight. (and from this I learn to be more careful in future edits)

Comment: No problem man. Out of curiosity, why does `while` have a font change to blue, but `While` does not? That originally made me think `while was correct.`

Comment: @ibayibay1 Black-colored symbols are either built-in symbol names (e.g. functions, settings variables, etc) or symbols that you've assigned values in your own code. Blue-colored symbols are those that don't yet have an assigned value or meaning. `While` is the built-in control-flow construct, while `while` has no meaning by default. This is actually why your original definition updated only one board entry (the one above (`x--`) and to the left (`y--`) of your input); `while`'s lack of definition means that all of its "arguments" are evaluated once, in order, when it is first seen.

Comment: @ibayibay1 Btw, the following is a great doc page to read to effectively understand the evaluation mechanism of *Mathematica*: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/Evaluation.html Reading & understanding this is essential for intermediate/advanced programming with *Mathematica*. For basic things, one can scrape by without it.

Answer (score 2):

**Update:** Setting only the major diagonal to 1 (original post set both diagonals to 1):

```
 ClearAll[diagsF2, saF2];
 diagsF2 = Module[{ind = {#, #2}},(Band[ind, Automatic, # {1, 1}] ->1) & /@ {1, -1}] &;
 saF2 = SparseArray[diagsF2[#1, #2], {#3, #4}] &;

 saF2[2, 3, 5, 5] // Normal
 (* {{0,1,0,0,0},{0,0,1,0,0},{0,0,0,1,0},{0,0,0,0,1},{0,0,0,0,0}} *)
 saF2[3, 5, 5, 5] // Normal
 (* {{0,0,1,0,0},{0,0,0,1,0},{0,0,0,0,1},{0,0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0,0}} *)

 Row[MatrixForm /@ {saF2[2, 3, 5, 5], saF2[3, 5, 5, 5],  saF2[4, 2, 5, 5]}]
```

[image]

```
board = ConstantArray[0, {10, 6}]; (* @billisphere's example *)
Fold[Composition[Unitize, Plus], board, 
     saF2[##, 10, 6] & @@@ {{8, 2}, {6, 5}, {1, 5}}] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

---

**Original post:**

```
ClearAll[diagsF, saF];
diagsF = Module[{ind = {#, #2}}, (Band[ind, Automatic, #] -> 1) & /@Tuples[{1, -1}, 2]] &;
saF = SparseArray[diagsF[#1, #2], {#3, #4}] &;

saF[2, 3, 5, 5] // Normal
(* {{0,1,0,1,0},{0,0,1,0,0},{0,1,0,1,0},{1,0,0,0,1},{0,0,0,0,0}} *)

saF[1, 5, 5, 5] // Normal
(* {{0,0,0,0,1},{0,0,0,1,0},{0,0,1,0,0},{0,1,0,0,0},{1,0,0,0,0}} *)

Row[MatrixForm /@ {saF[2, 3, 5, 5], saF[1, 5, 5, 5], saF[3, 5, 5, 5]}]
```

[image]

Comment: +1 Another nice example: `Normal@saF[6, 1, 11] /. (1) :> Style[1, Red]` contrasted with `saF[6, 11, 11]`.

Comment: @eldo, thank you... Highlighting the initial entry may be a good variation too.

Answer (score 0):

```
n = 10; 
board = ConstantArray[0, {n, n}]; 
diag1[x0_, y0_] := 
  Module[{x = x0, y = y0, satis}, 
         satis = Select[ Plus[{x, y}, #] & /@ Range[-(n - 1), n - 1], 
                         Max[#] <= n \[And] Min[#] >= 1 &];
         MapAt[# + 1 &, board, satis]]
```

Answer (score 0):

May be something like this also will help:

```
dig[x_, y_, n_] := SparseArray[{Band[{x, y} - (Min[x, y] - 1)] -> 1}, {n, n}] // MatrixForm

dig[3,2,5]
```

[image]

Comment: This is a near-duplicate of the second part of the answer I provided (~9 hours beforehand).

Comment: @billisphere I just focused on your answer now. yes they are almost similar.